# Tag count partially obstructed for longer tags when adding to question

Tags: bug, tags, design

When attempting to add a tag with a long name such as [producer-consumer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/producer-consumer), the "learn more" link obstructs the count (for this tag, it should read 26, not 2).  I suppose this has to do with the display not resizing if needed, but I don't remember if that was ever the case.

[image]

Comment: Btw this is the case on Stack Overflow too. For example if you try `google-app-engine`